# Method to Compare variable in Java

Tags: java, list, variables, methods, compare

Writing a code which in the superclass has a method called compareTo() and must be implemented in the tester class.

My problem is that I can't get the compareTo() method to work in the Animal class. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Code so far:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

abstract class Animal implements Comparable<Animal> {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int size;

    // Default Constructor
    public Animal(String firstName, String lastName, int size){
        super();
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        size = 0;
    }

    // Setters and Getters
    public void setFirstName(String firstName){
        firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName){
        lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setSize(int size){
        size = size;
    }
    public int getSize(){
        return size;
    }

    // CompareTo method
    public int compareTo(Animal compareAnimal) {

        String compareFirstName = ((Animal) compareAnimal).getFirstName();
        return firstName;

    }


    // Abstract method to be implemented in subclasses
    abstract String sound();

    // To be overriden in subclasses 
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return getFirstName() + getLastName() + getSize() + " says " + sound();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

    // Calls the constructor in the superlcass
    public Dog(String firstName, String lastName, int size){
        super(firstName, lastName, size);
    }

    // Implements the abstract methods in Animal class
    public String sound(){
        return "woof";
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Cat extends Animal {

    // Calls the constructor in the superlcass
    public Cat(String firstName, String lastName, int size){
        super(firstName, lastName, size);
    }

    // Implements the abstract methods in Animal class
    public String sound(){
        return "meow";
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Dog dog1 = new Dog();
        Cat cat1 = new Cat();

        dog1.setFirstName("Patch");
        dog1.setLastName("Cabbage");
        dog1.setSize(5);
        System.out.println(dog1.toString());
        System.out.println();

        cat1.setFirstName("Felix");
        cat1.setLastName("Longbottom");
        cat1.setSize(3);
        System.out.println(cat1.toString());
        System.out.println();

        // Create new ArrayList
        LinkedList<Animal> animalList = new LinkedList<>();

        // Add animals to the animalList
        animalList.add(dog1);
        animalList.add(cat1);

        // Sort by first name
        List <String> firstName = new LinkedList<String>( );
        try{
            File file = new File("Animals.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                firstName.add(line);
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Iterator<String> itr = firstName.iterator( );
        while ( itr.hasNext( ) ) {
            String person = itr.next( );
            System.out.println(person);
        }
        Collections.sort(firstName);

        class InnerClass implements Comparator {
            // body
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what is happening? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to use the compareTo method to sort by firstName in the tester class but what I am attempting currently, will not allow that outcome to happen. @SteveClanton

Comment: @SteveClanton in the Animal class, I wanna use the compareTo method to compare firstName and then in the tester use Collections.sort() to sort the list by firstName and then override the compareTo method to sort by other variables.

Comment: Looking at your `compareTo` method...what is it that you are comparing to what? Hint: you want to compare `compareAnimal` to `this` in the method. You don't want to return the first name. You need to compare the first name of the `compareAnimal` to the first name of `this`. When you compare those two strings to each other, you want to return the result of that comparison.

Comment: @SteveClanton something like this?: public int compareTo(Animal compareAnimal) {
 
            int result = this.firstName.compareTo( compareAnimal );
            System.out.println(result);
        }

Comment: pretty close. except you should return result, instead of printing it to the console.

Comment: Your "default" Animal constructor just drops its arguments on the floor and doesn't assign any member fields

Answer (score 0):

Your compareTo method doesn't make sense:

```
 // CompareTo method
public int compareTo(Animal compareAnimal) {
    String compareFirstName = ((Animal) compareAnimal).getFirstName();
    return firstName;
}
```

First of all, this is not going to even compile, because you're returning a String for a method that is supposed to return an int. You should compare `compareFirstName` with the `firstName` and return something.

Hint - The String library has something very similar to compare 2 strings and return an Int.

Comment: When I change the public int compareTo to String, it still won't work

Comment: It won't work because you're implementing the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, which needs you to return an int for the ```compareTo``` method.

Comment: Changing the int to String isn't the correct thing to do. You need to do some comparison between compareAnimal and ```this```, and return the integer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This code shouldn't compile. Your method should return an `int`, not a `String`.

```
//no comparison happens...just trying to return first name
public int compareTo(Animal compareAnimal) {
    String compareFirstName = ((Animal) compareAnimal).getFirstName();
    return firstName; //firstName is not an int!!
}
```

Also, nothing is being "compared" in your `compareTo` method. You need to compare the `compareAnimal` that is passed in to *something*, and that something is `this`. Instead of returning the first name, you need to get the first name from both objects and compare them:

```
public int compareTo(Animal compareAnimal) {
    String otherName = compareAnimal.getFirstName();
    return firstName.compareTo(otherName);
}
```

Also, note that I don't cast `compareAnimal` to `Animal` because that is already the type of the parameter. If I passed it in as an `Object` (as is the case when you implement `equals`, I would need to cast.